# Aggregate same user events into two different windows

Tags: python, streaming, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to write a simple pipeline with Apache Beam. Let's say I am taking in user requests that look something like:

`(country, user_id, score, timestamp)`

I just want to sum up the total score for all users per country, accumulated per minute and 10 minutes. However, there is a caveat that I want to take the latest score per user, per bucket. Meaning, if I have two records:

```
('USA', 1, 10, 62)
('USA', 1, 4, 64)
```

and assuming they map to the same minute bucket, I would like to keep the second record (the later one with score of 4).

How do I do this efficiently? Right now, I am taking the user event stream and piping it to two separate branches- one that computes this aggregate per minute and one that computes it per 10 minutes. Clearly, a lot of computation is being doubled here. Ideally, we would be able to re-use the calculations per 1 minute window to add up to the 10 minute window but I can't quite figure out how to do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not that big a deal to pipe the elements to two different branches, but yes you can probably do this in a way that avoids duplicating the aggregations.

Assuming that your 10 minute and 1 minute windows can evenly convert to each other (Fixed-time Windows should work fine for this), you can do the following:

`Assign 1 min. windows -> Aggregate -> Assign 10 min. windows -> Aggregate`

After the first aggregation (likely some type of Combine), the resulting elements should have the latest timestamp from the combined elements (this can be modified by changing the [TimestampCombiner](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.20.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/TimestampCombiner.html)). This means that as long as the windows line up evenly when you convert from one to the other, the second aggregation should be aggregating all the same data as your original approach.

For the second part of your question, to keep the latest timestamped element of a window and drop the other elements, you'll want to implement a custom [CombineFn](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.20.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Combine.CombineFn.html) that keeps the most recent element. Now in order to actually read the timestamps of the elements from a CombineFn you'll first need to use [Reify.timestamps](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.20.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Reify.html) to attach the timestamps to the element. And you'll probably want your CombineFn to output your original element type without the timestamp. So altogether it'll look like this (PCollections in square brackets so you can see the types):

`[ElementT] -> Reify.timestamps -> [TimestampedValue<ElementT>] -> Combine -> [ElementT]`